# Validate web url JavaScript to accept url entry google.com

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, url, web

I have the following regex

```
RegExp("((http|https)(:\/\/))?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]{1}){2}[a-zA-z0-9]+(\/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\/?",
   "i");
```

Works fine but shows the following pattern of url as invalid

> eg:"google.com"

I thank you for ur answers.

Comment: @Chris -1. Did you look carefully at the regex? `((http|https)(://))?` ... it means **optional**.

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Perhaps we can find another (much shorter and clear) regex.

Comment: I wanted www optional too but now i got the answer I used this ^(https?://|www\\.)?[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}

Answer (score 1):

Your code requires at least `something.something.something`, e.g. `stuff.google.com`. Trade the `{2}` for a `+` to allow for second-level domains.

```
RegExp("((http|https)(://))?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]{1})+[a-zA-z0-9]+(/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*/?", "i");
```

I'll add that there are several other...oddities about this regex (like using `{1}` and `[.]`) and that it doesn't account for some valid domains (like `something-something.com`). Also, you can use regex literals in JS, like `var regex = /just a regex/`. So I recommend some reading.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply. I did this ^(https?://|www\\.)?[\.A-Za-z0-9\-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}   and it works as required but I wan it to accept a space in front of the url in-case the user mistakenly types space b4 url. I know its \s* but how should i put it in the pattern I have mentioned?

Comment: Oh oh! its (^|[ ]) Thanks for you time though.

Comment: Instead of `(^|[ ])`, which isn't quite right, use `^ ?` or `^ *`.